# Sending message to whatsapp from Android app

Tags: android, image, message, whatsapp

How can we send an image directly to whatsapp from android app? I tried using

```html
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
Uri imageuri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), b);
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageuri);

                sendIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivity(sendIntent);
```

the above code opens send window of whatsapp. Is there any other way so that image will directly be sent without opening whats app window?

Comment: That's completely up to the WhatsApp devs. If the way they've implemented a photo sharing api is to have the intent open the WhatsApp window, that's what is going to happen.

Comment: without opening whatsapp window, then whom to send image..?

Comment: without opening whats app send window. Like using facebook sdk we can share image without actually going to facebook.

Comment: @AnaghaMagar check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24278082/send-whatsapp-message-in-background-or-send-message-and-close-the-app-in-android?rq=1 , what you're trying to do seems to be not possible

Answer (score 3):

**Android intent system**

Like most social apps on Android, WhatsApp listens to intents to share media and text. Simply create an intent to share text, for example, and WhatsApp will be displayed by the system picker:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

However, if you prefer to share directly to WhatsApp and bypass the system picker, you can do so by using [setPackage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setPackage(java.lang.String)) in your intent:

```
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
This would simply be set right before you call startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Similarly you can use Android's intent system to send media through WhatsApp, once again, using setPackage to restrict the package to WhatsApp if you only want to send to WhatsApp. Check this [developer page](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html) for more information.

**Custom URL Scheme**

WhatsApp provides a custom URL scheme to interact with WhatsApp:

If you have a website and want to open a WhatsApp chat with a pre-filled message, you can use our custom URL scheme to do so. Opening whatsapp://send?text= followed by the text to send, will open WhatsApp, allow the user to choose a contact, and pre-fill the input field with the specified text.

Here is an example of how to write this on your website:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20World!">Hello, world!</a>
```

*// NOT ORIGINAL TEXT: You can call this endpoint through your Java code too*

Found in: https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/es/android/28000012

Comment: How can I return back from whatsapp after sending message to my app?

Comment: @Anagha Magar: Was my answer helpful for you? If that was the case please tag it as the solution to help future users with the same problem :)